# Background image not appearing in compiled CHM file - Html workshop

Tags: html, chm, html-help-workshop

I've recently re-compiled a .chm file as a lot of changes needed to be made in each html file.

The main problem I'm having when simply recompiling these files is the background image. The code in one of the html files is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>How to Create a File</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Design"
  href="design.css" />
  <!--(Style Sheet)===================================================-->
  <style>
body { background-image:url("Background.gif"); background-repeat:repeat; background-attachment:scroll;  }</style>
</head>
```

The compiled version that was there before worked and kept the background. I have simply changed the text in the html files using Amaya and now it doesn't work!

The other problem is that if I rename all the files and change the index files etc accordingly, I ALSO loose the boxes I have around titled sections etc. So I have had to resort back to the old named and seriously unorganised files!

All of the images I'm using are in the same folder so this is not the problem.

Does any one know why this is happening? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you use this method instead  backgrond-image  and second think background repeat
You want repeat-x or repeat-y  or both side  repeat any one choose.

```
<style>
 body {
 background:url(Background.gif); 
 background-attachment:scroll;
 background-repeat:repeat;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The problem is, is that I know this method worked with the old compiled file, it just doesn't work now..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue for you...but in order to get your background to work, your style **must** be placed inline -- i.e. in the tag... in your case, the body tag. Background images will not work in a compiled CHM via linked stylesheet or by styles placed in the header.

You need to do:

```
<body style="...attributes here;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a background image path into **.hhp** file, **[FILES]** section.

For example:

```
[FILES]
  index.html
  ...
  background.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you are using the Microsoft Document Explorer. Give the image source path the full url as revealed when right clicking an image and looking at its properties:

```
ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/MS.VSIPCC.v80/something/something/background.gif
```

But an even better way is to use JavaScript to dynamically add the background image to the style of an element. You can do this with jQuery or with pure JavaScript.

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").css("background-image","url('images/css-background.jpg')");
});
```

With pure JavaScript:

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
style.styleSheet.cssText = '#example {  background: url(' + url + 'images/css-background.jpg) }';
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert image to base 64 first and then,

- For use in `<img>` elements:

  ```
  <img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBOR.....'/>
  ```
- For use as CSS background:

  ```
  url('data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...............'
  ```